# Grabbing Device Connect Exception in Class and passing it to pyQT main window

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a class that access an external LabJack device.  The Labjack device is connected via USB and its main function is to turn something on or off via a python command.  I'd like to pass an exception to my pyqt main window application just in case the labjack is not connected.  I'm not entirely sure how here is my LabJack class:

```
import u3

class LabJack:
    def __init__(self):

        try:
            self.Switch = u3.U3()
        except:
            print "Labjack Error"

        #Define State Registers for RB12 Relay Card

        self.Chan0 = 6008
        Chan1 = 6009
        Chan2 = 6010
        Chan3 = 6011
        Chan4 = 6012
        Chan5 = 6013

#Turn the channel on
    def IO_On(self,Channel):
        self.Switch.writeRegister(Channel,0)


    #Turn the channel off
    def IO_Off(self,Channel):   
        self.Switch.writeRegister(Channel,1)

    #The State of the Channel
    def StateSetting(self,Channel):
        self.Switch.readRegister(Channel)
        if Switch.readRegister(Channel) == 0:
            print ('Channel is On')
        else:
            print('Channel is Off')

    #Direction of Current Flow
    def CurrentDirection(self,Channel):
        self.Switch.readRegister(6108)
        print self.Switch.readRegister(6108)
```

Here is my pyqt code:

```
import re
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys
from LabJackIO import *
from Piezo902 import *
import functools

import ui_aldmainwindow

class ALDMainWindow(QMainWindow,ui_aldmainwindow.Ui_ALDMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ALDMainWindow,self).__init__(parent) 
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.ValveControl = LabJack()



        self.Valve_ON.clicked.connect(functools.partial(self.ValveControl.IO_On,self.ValveControl.Chan0))
        self.Valve_OFF.clicked.connect(functools.partial(self.ValveControl.IO_Off,self.ValveControl.Chan0))
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Valve Off')

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle('motif')
form = ALDMainWindow()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: This thread may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493081/pyqt-event-handlers-snarf-exceptions/14494564#14494564  I don't have time to dig back into this, but as I recall pyqt and exceptions can lead to a very particular kind of fun ;)  Good luck!

Comment: and where do you expect to have the exceptions raised? During `__init__` or during call-backs?  (this really should go before my previous comment where I assumed you wanted them in call-backs)

Answer (score 0):

If your `LabJack` could inherit from `QObject` you could emit a signal when the exception is caught:

```
class LabJack(QtCore.QObject):
    switchFailed = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LabJack, self).__init__(parent)
        try:
            self.Switch = u3.U3()

        except:
            self.switchFailed.emit()
```

Then set up a slot within your `ALDMainWindow` to handle the exception:

```
        self.ValveControl = LabJack()
        self.ValveControl.switchFailed.connect(self.on_ValveControl_switchFailed)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_ValveControl_switchFailed(self):
        print "Handle exception here."
```