# Automatic Stack Trace not being given in threads other than the main thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pydev, xlrd

I have a rather large program which loads some data from an excel file and populates a form, this can take a long time due to the size of the file so I have been moving the loading function onto a separate thread, the only problem is for some reason in this new thread I am not getting an automatic stack trace in the console whenever an error occurs. It has just been failing silently which is making debugging it a real pain.

I am using pydev in eclipse, I wrote the following test case to be sure everything is working correctly.

```
    from PyQt4 import QtCore

class OtherThread(QtCore.QThread):


    def __init__(self):
        super(OtherThread, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        try:
            print(1/0)
        except Exception as e:
            print("exception caught in other thread: \n{0}".format(e))

class MainThread():

    def __init__(self):
        self.otherThread = OtherThread()

    def run(self):
        try:
            print(1/0)
        except Exception as e:
            print("exception caught in main thread: \n{0}".format(e))

        self.otherThread.run()

def main():
    mainThread = MainThread()

    mainThread.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run this both exceptions are caught properly and when I comment out the try block in the tread object it also works just fine, I get my stack trace as expected. I am really at a loss as to what is going on. Is there something I could have done to cause this behavior?

Here is the code of the program I am working on.

```
    def run(self):
        print("excel thread running")

        workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(self.path)
        worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('PNA Form')
# 
        currentRow = 13 # start grabbing pna data
        numRowStart = currentRow
        newPartCol= 0
        oldPartCol = 10
        descriptionCol = 2
# 
        numberOfRows = worksheet.nrows - 1
#     
        print("number of rows = {0}".format(numberOfRows))
        PNA = []
#         
        current_color = False
        while (currentRow < numberOfRows):

            print("about to parse excel rows")
            newPartCell = int(worksheet.cell(currentRow,newPartCol).value)
            oldPartCell = int(worksheet.cell(currentRow,oldPartCol).value)
            descriptionCell =  QtCore.QString(worksheet.cell(currentRow,descriptionCol).value)

            print("excel rows parsed: {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}".format(oldPartCell,newPartCell,descriptionCell,current_color))

            print("running line excel row {0}: {1}".format(currentRow, str(descriptionCell)))
            if not self.isStrikethrough(currentRow,0): #make sure the line does not have strike through
                #self.guiHandel.BOMVal.addPNARow(oldPN = oldPartCell, newPN = newPartCell, disc = descriptionCell)
                print("about to emit pna row tracker for {0}".format(descriptionCell))
                self.addPNARowTracker.emit(oldPartCell,newPartCell,descriptionCell)
                print("thread still running after pna row tracker emit")

            if (oldPartCell != "" and not self.isStrikethrough(currentRow,0)):
                PNA.append((num(oldPartCell),num(newPartCell)))
                current_color = not current_color
                #self.guiHandel.pnaVerticalLayoutScroll.addWidget(PNACell(oldPartCell,newPartCell,descriptionCell,color = current_color))
                print("about to emit addPNARow: {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}".format(oldPartCell,newPartCell,descriptionCell,current_color))
                self.addPNARow.emit(oldPartCell,newPartCell,descriptionCell,current_color)
                #self.guiHandel.widgetStack.append(PNACell(oldPartCell,newPartCell,descriptionCell,color = current_color))
                print("thread still running after add pna row emit")

            currentRow += 1

            #self.guiHandel.pbar.setValue(int(100*(currentRow-13)/numberOfRows))
            print("currentRow =",currentRow)
            self.updateProgress.emit(int(100*(currentRow-numRowStart)/(numberOfRows-numRowStart)))

        print(PNA)
        self.done.emit()
```

Here is the console output when it fails.

```
slot add pna row tracker called
running is about to return
about to emit addPNARow: 28458820, 28489881, INST CSTR-ASM,DIESEL,KM,UP,GAT, False
thread still running after add pna row emit
('currentRow =', 29slot add pna row called)

about to parse excel rows
Added addPNARow: 28458820, 28489881, INST CSTR-ASM,DIESEL,KM,UP,GAT, False
excel progress update called ------- progress = 20
```

When running through a debugger it stops at this line:

```
newPartCell = int(worksheet.cell(currentRow,newPartCol).value)
```

I tried wrapping it in a try block but it never got to the exception. The cell it is trying to read is blank.

What is going on here? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have just confirmed that the blank line is what is causing it to hang. I made a test case with a blank line for the 5th line of input and it failed. However I do not understand why, this is almost exactly the same code that I was using when all of this was done on one thread.

Comment: removed the int() and QString functions and now the code executes until the end properly, EX: `newPartCell = int(worksheet.cell(currentRow,newPartCol).value)` to `newPartCell = worksheet.cell(currentRow,newPartCol).value` I would still like to know why errors on this thread are not being caught properly though.

Comment: In my previous comment had said it was executing properly, This is not the case, it appears that the signals are transmitting the numeric data as gibberish, everything comes out double what it is supposed to be.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493081/pyqt-event-handlers-snarf-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the question found here: [error in pyqt qthread not printed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581496/error-in-pyqt-qthread-not-printed)

Basically you need to manually encapsulate the entire run method of the QThread object and then manually rethrow errors to stderr